# Traer datos sin intermitencia desde puerto serial

Tags: c#

Cree un programa que envía y recibe datos de los puertos **Com** esto lo hace correctamente pero al recibir los datos de la bascula los recibe pero son intermitentes, no muestra bien los datos

Descargue HyperTerminal para mirar lo que la bascula manda y manda lo siguiente 
ST,GS,+  0kg

El programa muestra esos datos pero intermitente es decir me muestra de a uno 
primero la S luego la t  luego la , y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a la g

primero quiero lograr dos cosas

1- que me muestre solamente  el  0kg

2- que no muestre de a uno en uno si no el  0kg entero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TxRx_SerialPort
{
    public partial class FormInicio : Form
    {
        public FormInicio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }


        //Muestra los puertos disponilbes del sistema 
        private void PuertosDisponibles()
        {
            foreach (string puertoDis in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                cmbPuertos.Items.Add(puertoDis);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PuertosDisponibles();
        }



        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }


        //Muestra los datoss recibidos del puero al textBox 
        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string datorx=serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            txtRx.Text = datorx.Trim();
        }


        //trea los datos del com o del puerto com1
        private void CmbPuertos_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = cmbPuertos.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            cmbPuertos.Enabled = false;

            try
            {
                serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPort1_DataReceived;
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selecciones otro puerto", "Puerto no disponible");
                cmbPuertos.Enabled = true;
            }
        }


        //nos comunicamos con los puertos 
        private void BtnEnviar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Write(txtTx.Text.Trim());
                txtTx.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se puedo enviar la información", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Puede arreglar el programa así quedo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con SerialPort.ReadLine() en vez de ReadExisting() qué te devuelve?

Comment: otra pregunta, en donde estas controlando el final de la lectura? ahi falta un iterador que mire la entrada hasta que no existan mas datos

Comment: tu segundo problema es simplemente un Instr sobre la cadena para sacar lo que queres...

Comment: La verdad es primera vez que trabajo con basculas de peso y se me a hecho difícil y logre esto

Comment: @Hackerman Pero no recibes el peso ya? A pesar de que sea por separado?

Comment: @AsieR_2 Si señor ya el recibo el peso,  el problemas es ver completo los datos no los muestra completos muestra letra por letra

Comment: Amigo @AsieR_2 el cambio de ReadExisting() por ReadExisting() funciono perfectamente ahora me toca es dejar solo el peso mira la imagen que subí

Comment: @Hackerman No entiendo tu última edición, ya lo tienes todo o te falta algo por hacer?

Comment: @AsieR_2 Ya esta terminado muchas gracias

Comment: @Hackerman Perfecto :D

Comment: @Hackerman Agrego solución para poder dar la pregunta por respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `SerialPort.ReadLine()` en vez de `SerialPort.ReadExisting()` para recuperar la línea completa.

Como se explica en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=netframework-4.8) :

`ReadExisting()` "Lee todos los bytes inmediatamente disponibles, basándose en la codificación, en la secuencia y el búfer de entrada del objeto SerialPort."

Mientras que en el caso de ([doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.8)) `ReadLine()` "Lee hasta el valor de NewLine en el búfer de entrada." Devolvíendote así la línea al completo y no los datos ya disponibles.

Destacar que, al menos en mi experiencia, no siempre funcionará correctamente y es posible que tengas que hacer uso de `ReadExisting()`.

En ese caso bastará con que hagas varias iteraciones hasta que completes la línea, puesto que, en las básculas la cadena siempre es la misma (si no hay problemas de comunicación).